# Hebrew calendar into FullCalendar library

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to integrate Hebrew calendar into FullCalendar library. There is a way to do it with already created functions of this library? [library](https://fullcalendar.io/)

If it's impossible how to do it manually? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FullCalendar is based in the moment.js library, which in turm is smart wrapper on top of JavaScript's native Date object. All this stack implements Gregorian calendar.

You can certainly display a Gregorian calendar with all texts translated into the Hebrew language, but I don't think you can use alternative calendars.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález can i implemented with "hack" or e.g. ?

Comment: All those libraries are open-source, if that's what you mean. If you google for *hebrew calendar in javascript* you'll find some reference implementations of the calendar. But I suspect that if you need to ask the price you can't afford the item ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hebcal](https://www.hebcal.com/home/1223/display-a-jewish-calendar-on-your-website-with-hebcal-fullcalendar-io) to import Hebrew dates and holidays to a FullCalendar calendar with just one line of code.

Here's a sample FullCalendar + Hebcal Hebrew calendar code snippet:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: "https://www.hebcal.com/hebcal/?cfg=fc&v=1&i=off&maj=on&min=on&nx=on&mf=on&ss=on&mod=on&lg=s&s=off&d=on",
        cache: true
    }
});
```